# Mongoose query find() returns nothing

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

I'm querying db with 2 conditions, keyword and user id, both returns correctly in console log but returns nothing, not null, or [], just blank. Something is wrong with the syntax?

```
app.get("/api/client?", function (req, res) {

console.log("Search > " + JSON.stringify(req.query));
//Search > {"keyword":"emily","filterby":"5a25f3d1d4b3e30792dd53ca"}

var keyword = req.query.keyword;
var user_id = req.query.id;

Client.find({
  $and: [{
      "firstname": new RegExp('^' + keyword + '$', "i")
    },
    {
      userid: user_id
    }
  ]
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  res.status(200).json(result);
  console.log("Result is... " + result)
  //Result is

});
});
```

Alternatively, I tried without query, just search all based on user id and it works, it returns all records in db

```
app.get("/client", function (req, res) {
var user_id = req.query.id;

Client.find({
  userid: user_id
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  res.status(200).json(result);

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! Noob mistake, I was caught up with what was working in search all, var user_id = req.query.id but in fact when I passed in "filterby", based on

```
console.log {"keyword":"emily","filterby":"5a25f3d1d4b3e30792dd53ca"}
```

so it should be

```
var keyword = req.query.keyword;
var **filterby** = req.query.id;

Client.find({
   $and: [{
       "firstname": new RegExp('^' + keyword + '$', "i")
       },
       {
       userid: **filterby**
       }
     ]
   }
```